# Как выявить отличия объектов, на которых модель дает наибольшую ошибку, от остальных?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных

[Решаю задачу оттока.](https://www.kdd.org/kdd-cup/view/kdd-cup-2009/Data) Одна из идей оптимизации модели заключается в том, чтобы взять лучшую на текущий момент времени модель и посмотреть, на каких объектах достигается наибольшая ошибка в предсказании. Сделать это довольно просто: предсказать вероятность (`predict_proba`) и посмотреть, где вероятность истинного класса очень мала (например, меньше 0.1).

Подскажите, что делать далее? Как найти наибольшее отличия?

Мысли:

- Посмотреть «seaborn pairplot». Не очень информативно, так как много признаков. Все не посмотреть, а если и посмотреть, то обязательно что–нибудь упустишь.
- Для признаков с непрерывными значениями можно посчитать среднее, отклонение и выбрать те, которые отличаются от общей массы.
- Для категориальных можно искать уникальные значения.

Что можно добавить в этот список? Есть ли готовы библиотеки для подобных задач?